# Can't add an UTF-8 string into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, insert

I can't add an UTF-8 string into MySQL DB. Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $temp='papà';
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUE ('$temp')") or die(mysql_error());
     ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

the variable in DB is a CHAR(120) and with a non-utf8 string it works properly.
The error is the generic "You have an error in your SQL Syntax ecc."

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the character? MySQL's UTF8 isn't "real" UTF8. Did you try utf8mb4?

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Yeah, tried also with utf8mb4 right now, nothing seems to change. The character is, for example, the € (euro symbol) which is saved as â¬

Comment: Silly question but is your PHP file actually encoded in UTF-8 by your text editor?

Comment: Please show us the rest of the Syntax error message -- it points to where the error is !

Comment: `â¬` implies Mojibake, which implies that you neither had the `SET NAMES`, nor did you have the column defined to be `utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        $temp='papà';
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUE ('$temp')") or die(mysqli_error());
     ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

stop using `mysql_*` and start using `mysqli_*` or use PDO

Answer (score 0):

After converting to `mysqli_*`, use `set_charset`.  Don't do the rest of the SETs.  (`PDO` has the charset in the dsn.)

Is the column in the table `CHARACTER SET utf8`?

Are the bytes in the encoded utf8-encoded?  In `utf8`, then hex for `à` is `C3A0`.  In `latin1`, it is `F0`.

It is almost always better to use `VARCHAR` than `CHAR`.

If you have more troubles, do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM`coment`...;` -- that will probably give the best clue of what still broken.